# How can i reset the timer if my button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have a textview and i made a timer to decrease from 45 seconds to 0

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            t1.setText("00:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            if(millisUntilFinished<=10000){
                t1.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            t1.setText("Tempo acabado");
            b1.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }.start();
```

I want after the time has expired give the option for the user to click the b1 button and restart the timer

Comment: use `new CountDownTimer(4500,1000)` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create instance of `CountDownTimer`, then when you need to restart you can perform `cancel` and `start` on that instance.

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {
    //......................
}
//Start at first
countDownTimer.start();

//Restart when button is pressed
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
        countDownTimer.cancel(); 
        countDownTimer.start();
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(view -> restartTimer());

    restartTimer();
}

private void restartTimer() {
    b1.setEnabled(false);
    new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            t1.setText("00:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            if (millisUntilFinished <= 10000) {
                t1.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            t1.setText("Tempo acabado");
            b1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.start();
}
```